# how to change widget text in a custom alert dialog from fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

so I try to make a custom Loading Dialog like this

[image]

and here is the class

```
class LoadingDialog(mActivity: Activity) {

    private var dialog: AlertDialog
    private var dialogView : View

    init {

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
        val inflater = mActivity.layoutInflater
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading,null)
        builder.setView(dialogView)
        builder.setCancelable(false)

        dialog = builder.create()

    }

    fun show() {
        dialog.show()
    }

    fun dismiss() {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

}
```

and here is the xml of Loading Dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Please Wait"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

instead of hard code "Please Wait ...." , I want to set custom loading message from fragment/activity

in my fragment, i want to set my custom message like this

```
val loadingDialog = LoadingDialog(mActivity)
loadingDialog.show("custom message in here")
```

but I don't know how to access the widget from my Alert Dialog class.

java or kotlin is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun show(yourMessage: String) {
    dialogView.textView_message.text = yourMessage
    dialog.show()
}
```

you can access your textView in show function like that and set your passed String parameter as its text

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize the `textview_message` in `LoadingDialog` class,

```
class LoadingDialog(mActivity: Activity) {

    private var dialog: AlertDialog
    var messageTextView: TextView // <----
    private var dialogView : View

    init {

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
        val inflater = mActivity.layoutInflater
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading,null)
        messageTextView = dialogView.findViewById( R.id.textView_message ) // <---
        builder.setView(dialogView)
        builder.setCancelable(false)

        dialog = builder.create()

    }

    fun show() {
        dialog.show()
    }

    fun dismiss() {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

}
```

Then access it in the `Fragment` class,

```
val loadingDialog = LoadingDialog(mActivity)
val messageTextView = loadingDialog.messageTextView
loadingDialog.show("custom message in here")
```